# giter8 escape with '\$'

Tags: scala, giter8

I'm developing giter8 templates for Scala project.
All the templates were running as expected. However, today I faced with error:

```
Exiting due to error in the template: /var/folders/zg/dspycv2d6sqc92801kmqy3yw0000gn/T/giter8-75157374435862
relative: $name__norm$/src/main/resources/prod-application.conf, toPath: /Users/***/., An unexpected error occurred while processing the template. Check that all literal '$' are properly escaped with '\$'
```

mentioned file is as follows:

```
akka {
  discovery {
    method = akka-dns
    kubernetes-api {
      pod-namespace = \${SERVICE_NAMESPACE}
      pod-label-selector = "app=$name;format="norm"$"
      pod-port-name = management
    }
```

I tried different options of $ escaping. I even deleted all the text and tried to build a template but I still receive the same error with pointing to the same file.

Does anyone know possible way to solve this?